# Android File.delete not working

Tags: android

Im trying to delete an image file after I saved it to SD card, but the delete function is not working.  Any help will be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
// Save image to SD card
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(); 
File file = new File(path, "tmpimage" + ".jpg"); 
....
....
....
// Delete image from SD card
file.delete();
```

Later on I found out that I was actually deleting the file. The File.delete function actualy was working ok. I was saving the image also to the Gallery and was expecting the file.delete to remove it from Gallery. Thanks everyone for answering my question.

Comment: check whether the file existed or not.

Comment: can you print the boolean returned by the `delete()` method?

Comment: Please add your own answer and mark it as accepted, so this question can be closed.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing same issue. Did you find the solution? My boolean value is true!

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to add below permission in manifest, just check it if not.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already have that permission in the manifest. When I test for file existence, I get true even though the file exists and I'm using the same file path when I created the file.