# File.delete() is failing

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to delete some files with .delete() method, but the method seems to be not working.

Example file directory: “/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/something/68419.jpg”

My code:

```
File deletefile = new File(path); //The path is in the format I said
boolean didIt = deletefile.delete()
//didIt is false
```

I am using write&read external storage permissions.
The code was tested on Android 10.

Also, this person has the same code as me but theirs work, apparently.
[Android File.delete not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081861/android-file-delete-not-working)

Comment: It is likely either that the path is wrong or that your program does not have permission to delete the file.

Comment: You need to check if the file exists in that location first. assuming you have added the permimssion.

Comment: @khelwood The path is in the example format I gave so it should work. The program has the permission to delete the file

Comment: or the file is open somewhere else?  (?!  after next comment, "showing to user first")

Comment: @KidusTekeste I did check it while showing the photo to the user first. So the code wouldn'tve been triggered if the file didn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To analyze why the file cannot be deleted you should use the `Files.delete` method instead. It will throw an IOException with a message why the file cannot be deleted. If you use `File` you can simply convert it by using `deletefile.toPath()`;

Comment: Turns out it was because my program was still counting as using the file, even after getting the data and showing it, like @user15244370 suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file exists first.

```java
File deletefile = new File(path); //The path is in the format I said
boolean didIt = deletefile.delete()
//didIt is false
if (deletefile.exists()) {
    // you can delete
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did check it because I was showing the photo to the user first. So the code couldn't have been triggered if the file didn't exist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659789/6021740 Please check this answer. There are different forms of getting the real path.

Comment: I checked what you said & it shows that the file exists but couldn't be deleted.